# Annotate reverse related object via Django QuerySet

Tags: python, sql, django

**The situation**

Suppose I have the followings models:

```
class Garage(models.Model):
    width = ...
    height = ...

class Car(models.Model):
   garage = models.ForeignKey('Garage', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   brand = ...
```

Now suppose I have to find all garages with `width > 30` and containing Toyota cars.

Then I may do a simple query like this:

```
results = Garage.objects.filter(width__gt=30, car__brand__icontains='Toyota')
```

**The problem**

Showing my results grouped by Garage I need to highlight the Toyota cars, like this:

```
GARAGE A
Volvo C30
Toyota Prius <---highlight this
Saab 93

GARAGE B
Toyota Yaris <---highlight this

GARAGE C
Fiat 500
Toyota C-HR <---highlight this
```

[Django annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) appears not to be working with related fields.

Any smart solution?

N.B. *I need to do the query on Garage model (not on Car).*

**EDIT**

To clarify my question, I have a search form in frontend. The user may search garage attributes and/or car attributes.

In my results I want to show the useful garages (they that match the query). For each garage I want to show *every* car in it, but I need to highlight *only* the cars that match the query.

Given the above example (which is a simplified version), in my template I have something like this:

```
{% for garage in results %}
     <div>
     Garage #{{garage.id}}: W {{garage.width}} x H {{garage.height}}
         <div>
         {% for car in results.car_set.all %}
             <span> {{car.brand}} {{car.model}} ... </span>
         {% endfor %}
         </div>
     </div>    

{% endfor %}
```

Everything is fully working. But I still need to highlight the cars of interest (e.g. "Toyota" cars only).

Hope I am clear now. Thank you all.

Comment: did the query `icontains='Toyota'` returned ***Volvo*** as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Endre Both: I need to identify the cars of interest among the others!

Comment: Maybe you could post either your template or some pseudocode to show what you want to do. Do you want a query that selects all garages with all related Toyota models (but no other models)? Or what else?

Comment: @JPG Yes, the query `results` correctly returns garage objects, from which I can obtain all the cars inside them (so, Volvo, Toyota, Fiat, whatever...) iterating like `{% for car in results.car_set.all %}`

Comment: You can pass the query string to the template and then check if the brand name matches the string: `{% if query_string in car.brand %} ... add highlight class to the span or do whatever else you need {% endif %}`. It can get complicated if the user can query on different attributes though.

Answer (score 0):

Django annotate does support reverse relations expansion. You need to know the proper related name for your relation, I suggest you use the `related_name` property to define how the reverse lookup should be called like so:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
   garage = models.ForeignKey('Garage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cars')
   brand = ...
```

Then your query should be

```py
results = Garage.objects.filter(width__gt=30, cars__brand__icontains='Toyota')
```

Comment: I used the default related name. Ok. But your post does not answer the question.

Comment: Ok, what exactly is your question? Do you want to identify the cars whose name is 'Toyota' among all the cars in a garage? Where do you need this? In frontend? Why do you say you 'have to do the queryon Garage model'? Please clarify these points so a proper answer can be given